# さくらさくらの「ぞ」はどういう意味？

Tags: particles, song-lyrics

桜桜の歌詞で「匂いぞ出{い}ずる」と言った（どうやっていうの？）文があります。その文のぞはどういう意味ですか？助詞じゃないですか？

I don't really know how well I structured that. In any case, what is the functionality of ぞ in さくらさくら? I can only find web definitions for emphasis, at the end of sentences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This 「ぞ」 is a 係助詞{かかりじょし} (binding particle) from classical Japanese.

**History**: It was originally そ in the Nara period, then ぞ in the Heian period, gone in the Muromachi period except for people intentionally trying to sound poetic, such as the author of this poem.

**Semantics**: It stresses/emphasizes what it marks

**Syntax**: It occurs in the usual spots of a 係助詞 (the syntactic class containing は, も, こそ, でも, etc.), but in addition, it is followed by the 連体形 of a verb -- this phenomena occurs with a few other 係助詞 in Classical Japanese and is called 係り結び.

**Examples**:

> 右近**ぞ**見知りたる。呼べ！
> ukon zo misiritaru. yobe.
> "Ukon knows for sure. Call her!"
>
> みな鎧の袖を**ぞ**ぬらしける。
> mina yorohi no sode wo zo nurasikeru.
> "*Everyone* wet the sleeves of their armor."

In your case:

> 霞か雲か　匂い**ぞ**出{い}ずる
> kasumi ka kumo ka nioi zo izuru
> "Is it mist? Is it a cloud? The color radiates!"

(This 出ずる is in fact a newer spelling of the 連体形 of the 下二段活用動詞「[出づ](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E5%87%BA%E3%81%A5)」, 「出づる」, meaning that this sentence fits the bill.)

Comment: I think that 匂い (にほひ) stands for "hue" rather than "smell".

Comment: Oops, you are indeed correct that it's almost certainly not "smell" there... I should have checked a 古語辞典.